# .htaccess - Rewrite query string and redirect to directory

Tags: string, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have some old URL's that I want to fix because of a forum migration.

The old URL's look like:
http://www.example.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=666

I want to redirect them to:
http://www.example.com/forum/missions/666

My approach is this, but I'm scratching my head, because it doesn't work at all:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^TOPIC_ID=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^/forum$       /forum/missions/%1      [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: This seems like it's in reverse.  It seems like you want users to be able to go to http://www.example.com/forum/missions/666 and see what the server resolves as http://www.example.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=666.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is no .htaccess in `/forum/, you can use this **first rule** in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^TOPIC_ID=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^forum/topic\.asp$ /forum/missions/%1? [NC,L,R=302]
```

If there is a .htaccess in `/forum/`, then you can use this **first rule** in your `/forum/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^TOPIC_ID=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^topic\.asp$ /forum/missions/%1? [NC,L,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks, the first one just works like intended. I can go on from here with this syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest this, but cannot really try from here :)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^forum/topic.asp\?TOPIC_ID=([0-9]+)$ forum/missions/$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: You can't do that, because the query string (part after ?) is not in the RewriteRule used string.

Comment: I definitely need a lesson about this :)